# How do I calculate the vertical travel of an oscillating arm with a fulcrum?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, classical-mechanics

I'm trying to calculate the vertical travel of the longer arm in a motion like this:

[image: Simulation]

I've had a go at defining the variables involved:

[image: Variables]

Where the measurables are:

- S = Short arm length
- L = Long arm length
- F = Distance from origin of L to the fulcrum

And the unknowns are:

- V = Total vertical travel distance of L

I'd like to express V in terms of the measurable variables (perhaps more than defined above, if I've missed any, which is likely).

I don't have much knowledge in this area and no idea how to approach working this out formally, short of brute forcing the measurable variables and working backwards.

Comment: Do you have a name for this setup? It looks like some kind of linkage but I don't know the terminology in that area well enough to say more.  Also, here is a Geogebra implementation of this motion: https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/gykwvwke

Comment: Your variables are sufficient and not redundant, which is good, but I would have measured the distance to the fulcrum from the fixed point of the short arm rather than from the "origin" of the long arm, which is only at that particular point for one instant during a revolution.

Comment: If I take the fulcrum as the origin of the coordinate system, then the curve is of the form $p(x,y)=0$ where $p$ is some (complicated) degree-6 polynomial in $x,y$. The vertical minimum/maximum points then satisfy $\partial_x p(x,y)=0$ as well, so in principle one can solve to find the vertical range. However, this is is likely analytically intractable due to $p=0$ and $\partial_x p=0$ not being especially nice. So one will likely have to be content with particular choices of parameters and numerical root-finding.

Answer (score 3):

Let's call $B\mathord:(b\mathbin;0)$ the apex of the fulcrum, $O\mathord:(0\mathbin;0)$ the fixed point of the short arm, and $M\mathord:(s\cos\vartheta\mathbin;s\sin\vartheta)$ the mobile point of the mechanism; one calculates that the leftmost extremity $E$ of the long arm has these coordinates:
\begin{eqnarray*}
x(\vartheta)\mkern-8mu&=&\mkern-8mu s\cos\vartheta-(s-b)\frac{s\cos\vartheta-b}{\sqrt{b^2+s^2-2bs\cos\vartheta}}\\[5pt]
y(\vartheta)\mkern-8mu&=&\mkern-8mu s\sin\vartheta\left(1-\frac{s-b}{\sqrt{b^2+s^2-2bs\cos\vartheta}}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
where $s>0$ is the length of the short arm (thus $L=s-b$).
In the following picture, we take as an example $b=-20$ and $s=12$; this corresponds to
$\displaystyle x(\vartheta)=12\cos\vartheta-32\frac{3\cos\vartheta+5}{\sqrt{30\cos\vartheta+34}}$ and
$\displaystyle y(\vartheta)=12\sin\vartheta\left(1-\frac{8}{\sqrt{30\cos\vartheta+34}}\right)\cdot$

[image]
Searching for which values of $\vartheta$ is $y$ extremal leads to a most complicated equation (and some pessimism)…
Numerically —according to MacOS Grapher.app— $y$ is maximal for $\vartheta_0\approx3.737$ (about $214^\circ$), and $y(\vartheta_0)\approx11.057)$.

---

In the special case where $s=-b$ —i.e. when $F=0$— the coordinates of point $E$ become much simpler:
$x(\vartheta)=b(2\cos(\vartheta/2)-\cos\vartheta)$ and $y(\vartheta)=b(2\sin(\vartheta/2)-\sin\vartheta)$ (for $-\pi\leqslant\vartheta\leqslant\pi)$; the corresponding trajectory for $E$ is no longer a closed curve but *a piece of cardioid* (in red below), limited to $x\leqslant b$.
Then $y(\vartheta)$ is maximal (resp. minimal) at $\vartheta=-\pi$ (resp. $\vartheta=\pi$), and $y(\pm\pi)=\mp2b$.
[image]
Once $b$ is fixed are there special values for $s$ (apart from $-b$) that lead to an “explicit” solution?